Unity Parameter IsRunning does not exist. Unity.Engine.Animator:SetBool (string,bool)
I try to make a survival Game like in this Tutorial here: https://youtu.be/_GzSfnJNNI4?si=UasH0Eb8Fc1zzP3a
my Problem is, that my Bunny is not hopping (Animation), sometimes it does, sometimes its not. I tried to rename the IsRunning to Forward in the Animator and in the Ai_Movement script. It doesnt worked. It doesnt hopped anymore. Than I undo it and the hopping animation doesnt worked anymore. In the Animator I choosed for the Idle the Idle Motion, for Run the Run Motion.
For the rabbit object I added the Ai_Movement script, Rigidbody, Box Collider and I think the Animator Parameters was already inside the object.
By the Animator Controller is the DemoAnimatorController from the pack.




Is there a chance the parameter has a space on the end? or its a different animator control?

you mean the is Running parameter in the script or something other? How can I check if its the right Animator Control? I think it was automatically inside the Prefab from the Rabbit. With the Bear there is not a problem

Did you attach the AI_Movement script at the same layer as animtion component?
